# MKDirections / calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler not working anymore in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7, directions

I have another problem now with MapKit / MKDirections.

After I got everything working fine, Swift 2.0 came out and the 
'calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler' method that looks like this:

```
directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler({(response:
            MKDirectionsResponse!, error: NSError!) in

            if error != nil {
                println("Error getting directions")
            } else {
                self.showRoute(response)
            }

        })
```

does not work any more.
It's giving me this error on line 1:

```
'(MKDirectionsResponse!, NSError!) -> Void' is not convertible to 'MKDirectionsHandler' (aka '(Optional<MKDirectionsResponse>, Optional<NSError>) -> ()')
```

Before the update this worked perfectly fine....
Thank you in advance for your help! :-)

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Comment: Below solution is not working? @QadirHussain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For swift 2.0:

```
let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler{
    response, error in

    guard let response = response else {
        //handle the error here
        return
       }
       self.showRoute(response)
    }
```

For more Info refer [THIS](https://github.com/vandadnp/iOS-8-Swift-Programming-Cookbook/blob/master/chapter-maps/Displaying%20Directions%20on%20The%20Map/Displaying%20Directions%20on%20The%20Map/ViewController.swift).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Sorry I'd upvote but I don't have enough reputation :/ This worked perfectly fine :) . It's new, this syntax, right?

Comment: Thanks . This was quite straight forward ^^

Comment: Great!! Happy coding.